# How to change WebDAV password locally

Tags: webdav

I can't figure out how to change the webdav password. I've done some searching, found many resources of how to add a new user to webdav, but nothing about changing password. Anyone know?

Comment: What WebDav server and/or client are you talking about?

Comment: Not going to lie, I don't have much knowledge on WebDAV. Trying to change the password of the default user (xampp) on my local machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Passwords are stored in webdav.htpasswd file.

If you open it, you will see an entry like this

*wampp:XAMPP with WebDAV:bc7f2b670e7e965e307feb30492e642e*

That's the entry for `user` wampp: in `realm` XAMPP with WebDAV: with `password` which is encrypted.

> To change password, you should use htdigest.exe.

See [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/programs/htdigest.html). It is used to create and update user authentication files. You should find in the bin directory of xampp installation.

To do that, do :

> htdigest.exe "pathto/webdav.htpasswd" "XAMPP with WebDAV" yourusername
>
> This will be returned:
>      Adding user yourusername in realm "XAMPP with WebDAV"
>
> You will then be asked for the password for yourusername
>
> New password: yourpassword
>
> Re-type new password: yourpassword

Reference: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=38897

Comment: How do you remove the default password?  I just deleted it from the `.htpasswd` file.  Afraid it will have a wicked backlash.

Comment: What about Linux installation of webdav (https://superuser.com/questions/1222679/change-password-of-webdav-user-in-linux-ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the content of the file `C:\Program Files\xampp\security\htpasswd.webdav` with your username, a colon and the password. Note: Everyone who can see this file can see the password!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about doing a password change at the server from a client, I don't believe WebDAV supports such a transaction.

You'd use something like a shell logon or a Web-based admin page to do this.

This always struck me as odd for a lot of network services, for example FTP or email.  It seems to be common though.

Comment: Rob said: "Trying to change the password of the default user (xampp) on my local machine"